# Построение микросервисов

Tags: база-данных, архитектура, микросервисы

Я разбираю микросервисы и немного не понимаю как из делить, чтобы не было крепкой зависимости. Например, у нас есть интернет библиотека, в которой есть книги. Например, первый сервис отвечает за книги, то есть их информацию. А второй за то, чтобы возвращать взятые книги. То когда взяли и когда вернули. По типу того.Бд в 1 сервисе понятна, id книги и ее информация. Как сделать бд у второго сервиса, если я там по сути должен хранить взятые книги(а точнее их id) и то, когда их вернут. Вопрос в том, что если из бд удалить книгу. То что будет со 2 икросервисом и её бд? Мне надо будет делать запрос и если что удалять её и из 2 бд? А если таких сервисом, которые посвящены будут на книге будет несколько?

Comment: В твоём сценарии книгу удалять нельзя, вне зависимости от архитектуры. Если книга выдавалась и возвращалась, то её нельзя удалять. Если она утрачена, т.е. её больше нельзя выдавать, то она просто должна быть помечена соответствующим флагом.

Comment: А по теме вопроса - даже если ты в первой удалил, в чём проблема подвисших записей во втором сервисе? Я не вижу сценария, в котором второй сервис понадобилось бы полность сканировать, его задача по ИД выдавать историю. Допустим, появился такой ИД, по которому историю уже не запросят никогда. Ну и что, пусть записи лежат.

Comment: Микросервисы делят обычно по связанному контексту (bounded context). В вашем случае вообще не понятно, зачем тут 2 сервиса, так как инфа по книгам и учет книг - довольно близкие вещи друг к другу, может они и должны быть в едином сервисе?